# WebElement resizing through dragAndDropBy is not working in Google Chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to test Resizable in chrome using `Actions.dragAndDropBy`, but not working.

My code is

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/resizable/");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("demo-frame")));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);     
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".// [@id='resizable']/div[3]"));
Thread.sleep(3000);
act.dragAndDropBy(element, 100, 100).build().perform();
driver.close();
```

I tried below also Actions.clickAndHold(WebElement) method also as below

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.clickAndHold(element).moveByOffset(100,100).release().build().perform();
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

To **resize** the *Resizable* element in *Chrome* using *Actions* class and `dragAndDropBy()` method you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class DragDrop_Resizable {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/resizable/");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.className("demo-frame")));
          WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se']")));
          new Actions(driver).dragAndDropBy(element, 100, 100).build().perform();
      }
  }
  ```
- Original Element Snapshot:

[image: original_element]

- Resized Element Snapshot:

[image: resized_element]